# On hover effect on a SVG group

Tags: d3.js, svg, onmouseover, onhover

I'm working on a pretty big map with lots of different areas and text on top of them, sort of like countries. I want to add a on mouse hover effect when hovering over this area. The effect should add a shadow and change its opacity. When I hover out of the area the opacity should go back to its original and the shadow effect should go away. I managed to do this but when I add text into this area it messes things up. The on hover effect gets called again when I hover on the text that's inside area when it shouldn't be called again at all. I made a fiddle that works until i hover on the text as well. I'm using the D3.js library for the coding.

```
 var groupAreas = "";

 groupAreas = d3.selectAll(".area-group");

 groupAreas.on("mouseover", fadeInArea)
   .on("mouseout", fadeOutArea)
   .on("click", zoomIn);

 var initialOpacity = 0;

 function fadeInArea() {
   //Get its initial opacity
   initialOpacity = d3.select(this).select("path").style("opacity");

   d3.select(this).transition(500).attr("filter", "url(#shadow-filter-1)").style("cursor", "pointer");
   d3.select(this).select("path").transition(500).style("opacity", 0.7);
 }

 function fadeOutArea() {
   d3.select(this).transition(500).attr("filter", null).style("cursor", "default");
   d3.select(this).select("path").transition(500).style("opacity", initialOpacity);

 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qx5u9uo4/6/

the area has an original opacity of 0.4. When i hover over the area it changes to 0.7 and the shadow effect is added. When I go out, it goes back to 0.4 as it should. Yet if i go in the area and also hover over the text the OnMouseOver gets called again and it then sets 0.7 as original opacity and thus never goes back to 0.4 again when I actually go outside the area.

I think the problem may lie with my order of DOM svg elements?

```
  <g class="area-group">
    <path id="area-1" d="M502.2 581.4h-53.5v-61l167.4 70.4v34.6H502.2z" />
    <text transform="translate(542.4 614)"> FOO </text>
    <text transform="translate(459.4 571.2)"> BAR </text>
    <text transform="translate(521.1 592.9)"> / </text>
  </g>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you just want to stop the `text` elements from receiving pointer events:

```
.area-group>text {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```